# How to work with time stamps?

Tags: r

I have the following timestamp column in R.

```
timestamp

03/08-18:30:59.660893 
03/08-18:31:38.243675 
03/08-18:31:38.243473 
03/08-18:31:44.635780 
03/08-18:31:59.779519 
03/08-18:31:59.795424 
03/08-18:31:59.798975 
03/08-18:31:59.803587 
03/08-18:34:35.570798 
03/08-18:34:35.569390 
03/08-18:34:42.408985 
03/08-18:34:42.405196 
03/08-18:34:42.559961 
03/08-18:34:42.558567
```

I am doing cluster analysis on this data set. Is there a way to convert the above column into a more workable data. Like events occurring within 5 minutes should be assigned the same numerical value to a new column in the data set. Or any other method is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: What if event2 is within 5 minutes of event1, & event3 is within 5 minutes of event2, but event3 is >5 minutes later than event1?

Comment: @gung Actually I haven't thought this through. But basically if event 1 is triggered at time t and if within t+5 the exact same event is triggered then it must be notified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way, provided you can supply a year, otherwise year will be 0. Change the number of minutes in `cut` to any other number.

```
library(lubridate)

t <- c("03/08-18:30:59.660893", "03/08-18:31:38.243675",
"03/08-18:31:38.243473",
"03/08-18:31:44.635780",
"03/08-18:31:59.779519",
"03/08-18:31:59.795424",
"03/08-18:31:59.798975",
"03/08-18:31:59.803587",
"03/08-18:34:35.570798",
"03/08-18:34:35.569390",
"03/08-18:34:42.408985",
"03/08-18:34:42.405196",
"03/08-18:34:42.559961",
"03/08-18:34:42.558567")

t1 <- paste0('2016/', t)

cut(parse_date_time(t1, '%Y/%m/%d-%H:M:S'), '2 min')
```